# Как создать установщик для jar

Tags: jar, java

Добрый день. Есть приложение написанное на java. Собрано оно в jar. Необходимо создать установщик под windows, создает директорию в программ файлс, копирует туда jar, создает ярлыки с рабочего стола и с панели, и если нет явы на машине то предлагает ее скачать и поставить. Может кто делал или знает что почитать?

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте [NSIS](nsis.sourceforge.net), или, например [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).

У NSISа странноватый скриптовый язык, зато много плагинов и готового кода типа [Java Launcher with automatic JRE installation](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Java_Launcher_with_automatic_JRE_installation).